# How can I eliminate the "non-nullable property must contain..." warning in EF only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullable-reference-types

So in EntityFramworks you declare a class with no constructor and all properties have a get and set. EntityFrameworks will load a row and populate the class using the setters.

When declaring a class for EF, the nullable setting for each property is used by EF to determine if the underlying database value can be null. So it won't work to set all properties to nullable.

In addition, even if that would work, I want to make use of the nullable setting. I want the compiler to know which properties might be null and which will not be. That is useful.

So, how can I keep the warning for non-nullable properties not being set, but have it turn off for EF classes?

The best I've come up with so far is to put the following at the top of the EF model classes:

```
#nullable disable
```

But I'm not wild on that because it will then ignore the warning on any code in that file, not just the model properties.

**Update:** As @gunr2171 said below #nullable disable is actually very bad because it turns off nullable reference types.

Comment: `#nullable disable` doesn't _ignore_ the warning, it _disables_ Nullable Reference Types. Can you _ignore_ the warning?

Comment: "So, how can I keep the warning for non-nullable properties not being set, but have it turn off for EF classes?" Can you show an example, this sounds contradictory.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization either `public required ... ` or `{ get; set; } = null!;` depending on version.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That's it! Please post as an answer and I'll select it. thank you.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you for pointing out the true (very bad) impact of nullable disable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice for using Nullable Reference Types for DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424673/best-practice-for-using-nullable-reference-types-for-dtos)

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is, use the required keyword (added in C# 11). That was added expressly for this situation.