What is the most appropriate default string value for a [Required] data annotation?
I'm learning model binding and validation for C# .NET 8 Razor Pages. I set up a simple input model to test validation (from ASP.NET Core Razor Pages in Action, Mike Brind):
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string CountryName { get; set; }
            [Required, StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        }

However I get the following compiler warning:
Warning CS8618 Non-nullable property 'CountryName' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable., same for CountryCode.
It's easy enough to understand I should assign a value to CountryName and CountryCode, or set them to nullable, but what is most correct and why?

public string CountryName { get; set; } = default!;
public string CountryName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public string CountryName { get; set; } = "";
public string? CountryName { get; set; }
public string? CountryName { get; set; } = default;
Something else


Does the control that this property is bound to accept Null and/or empty string? If so, then it's up to you (and an opinion based question, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424673/best-practice-for-using-nullable-reference-types-for-dtos)

If you're using C#11, then using the required modifier may be the most appropriate in your case.

@JohnathanBarclay: The required modifier doesn't apply because the model binder doesn't use an object initializer.

@madreflection No, but it gets rid of the compiler warning. Using [Required] ensures that a value is bound anyway.

Fair point.  I recently encountered a reflection-based initialization scenario where [Required] wouldn't have done anything, so I wasn't considering that behavior.

@gunr2171 In my example the InputModel doesn't actually bind to anything else yet, so it's up in the air. Thank you for the link.

There is no "most correct" answer. Just whatever you can live with consistently going forward. Personally, I disable Nullable in the project file.

This is just a warning which is tell you, we should set it to be not null. All the option you use is OK, In my opinion, if you don't want to have a nullable check inside your codes, you could use the public string CountryName { get; set; } = string.Empty; or public string CountryName { get; set; } = "";.
But since you have required validation inside your codes, it will not be null if you use the validation well, so there is no need to set the default value, you could also choose public string? CountryName { get; set; }.
Another way you could ignore this warning is modify the csproj as below：
<Nullable>disable</Nullable>

